# Calculate the sum of the double series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the sum of the double series:
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m^2n}{3^m(n3^m+m3^n)}$$

Comment: Replacing $m\leftrightarrow n\;,$ and Then Add these two series.

Comment: @juantheron nice trick! it also applies if one replaces $3$ by some generic $a<1$. Also we can write $m^{l+1}n^l$ in the numerator for $l\in N$

Comment: @juantheron Could you please clarify which are the two series?

Comment: @juantheron If you are going to post an answer I am ready to delete mine.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025317/calculation-of-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-fracm2n3n-leftm-cdo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints.

As suggested by the very useful comment of juantheron (which deserves all the merit of this post), consider the two sums
$$S_1=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m^2n}{3^m(n3^m+m3^n)}\quad\mbox{and}\quad S_2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2m}{3^n(m3^n+n3^m)}.$$
Then show:

i) $S_1=S_2$.

ii) 
$\displaystyle S_1+S_2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty
\left (\frac{m^2n}{3^m(n3^m+m3^n)}+ \frac{n^2m}{3^n(m3^n+n3^m)}\right)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{3^n}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{3^m}\right)$.

iii) Evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{3^n}$.

iv) Evaluate $S_1$.

Comment: Can we interchange the order of summation because the series is convergent?

Comment: We can interchange the order of summation because we are summing positive terms.

Comment: thanks, nice answer though!